# friendly id and devise error when using reserved word

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, friendly-id

I used friendly id to allow user access profile with their login name, but when I try to sign up with login name that has been reserved by the friendly Id, I got an error. It seems devise can't render the error message properly. The error just works fine when I'm using authlogic.

Friendly_id Config:

```
:reserved_words => ["index", "new", "users", "admin", "login", "logout", "books",
                    "administrator", "signup"],
```

Error:

```
FriendlyId::ReservedError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
FriendlyId::ReservedError
```

I'm using:

```
gem 'devise', '1.3.4'
gem 'friendly_id', '3.2.1.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works with friendly_id 4.0.0.beta14 on Rails 3.1.1

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name

after_validation :validate_reserved

def validate_reserved
  if @errors[:friendly_id].present?
    @errors[:name] = "is reserved. Please choose something else"
    @errors.messages.delete(:friendly_id)
  end
end
```

My friendly_id.rb initializer looks like this:

```
FriendlyId.defaults do |config|
  config.use :slugged, :reserved
  config.reserved_words = %w(new edit index show data)
end
```

Comment: This can be shortened to a one liner - `errors.add :name, *errors.delete(:friendly_id) if errors[:friendly_id].present?` as documented [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Reserved)

Comment: Inspecting these values at all will add them to the error array. Before checking to see if they are present i added `if !@errors.empty? && @errors[:friendly_id].present?`

Answer (score 1):

Or simply edit the `config/initilaizers/friendly_id.rb` file and add your reserved words to the

```
config.reserved_words = %w( [...] )
```

block, as the [documentation attests](https://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Reserved).

Answer (score 0):

After going through this [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/friendly_id/browse_thread/thread/136e1a67eee1719b), I added following in user.rb and it seems to work fine:

```
after_validation :validate_reserved

def validate_reserved
        slug_text
        rescue FriendlyId::BlankError
        rescue FriendlyId::ReservedError
        @errors[friendly_id_config.method] = "is reserved. Please choose something else"
        return false
end
```

I have also added a condition where it will rescue FriendlyId::BlankError as I am already checking it in my normal validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also alter your config/locales/en.yml or appropriate language file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        your_model_name:
          attributes:
            friendly_id:
              exclusion: 'name is a reserved word'
```

It reads like `Validation failed: Friendly name is a reserved word`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jerome it fixes my error
<%= link_to 'Surt', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
Not route user/sign_out simply adding sign_out to friendly_id reserved words

```
config/initilaizers/friendly_id.rb
config.reserved_words = %w(new edit index session login logout sign_out users admin
    stylesheets assets javascripts images)
```